# move_uploaded_file is not moving the temporary file over

Tags: php, apache, file-upload, upload, windows-server-2008-r2

I have Apache 2.4 installed on Windows and PHP running on the same server "Windows Server 2008 R2" without using IIS.

I have a PHP script that should upload files on to the server.

Here is my PHP code

```
if (!empty($_FILES) && $actualToken == $verifyToken) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath =  ROOT_FIXED . UPLOAD_DIR . $targetFolder;   //$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
    $targetPath = str_replace( "//", "/", $targetPath);
    $new_filename = USER_ID . '_' . time() . '_' . str_replace(" ", "_", $_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
    $targetFile = $targetPath . $new_filename;

    $fileParts = pathinfo($new_filename); 

    if (in_array(strtolower($fileParts['extension']),$fileTypes)) {
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);      
        $msg_res = trim($new_filename);
    } else {

        $msg_res = 'INVALID';
    }
}
```

When I upload the file I do see a .tmp file created in the designated temporary folder location. But after the file is uploaded it is removed from the temporary folder but it is not being moved to the permanent location for some reason.

I am not sure if it is a permission issue or not but I am attaching screenshots of the permissions on the folders.

I have also modified the php.ini file and added

```
upload_tmp_dir = 'C:\php\temp_files'
```

so the temp files should be going into the above location "and they are."

This screenshot show the Apache is Logging on as "Local system account"
[image]

This screenshot show the security settings on the folder where the file should be permanently moved to
[image]

Comment: Did you debug your script? Did you make sure that $targetFile contains a valid path? Did you make sure the execution is hitting the function move_uploaded_file? What's the final value of $msg_res?

Comment: yes, I did prior posting my question.

Comment: Did you check what move_uploaded_file is returning?

Comment: `$targetFolder` that's a stray variable. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: this `move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile)` returns 1.   I do have the display_errors and E_ALL but I don't see anything

Comment: Try changing the target path to something inside Apache DocumentRoot directory.

Comment: I am no longer getting the 302 error but the temp file is not being moved to the permanent path. I do not see any error but it does not make it to the final path